# Does it make sense to start a bounty to an answered question?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounties

When there is an accepted answer, should 'Start a bounty' option still be there?

[Accepted answer + start a bounty http://i.min.us/ibjd4G.png](http://i.min.us/ibjd4G.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone might find an existing question they have without being satisfied by the existing answer, even if one was marked accepted. This allows him/her to get new answers without posting a new question.

Comment: I feel like in that case it would make sense to create a new question and explain why the accepted answer to the earlier question is not acceptable.